# Combined HW/SW rec (system invokes both that can work together). Where to ask?

Tags: discussion, scope

I originally asked this [question about hypervisors and vGPU support on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/951093/278317), but it was deemed unsuitable, and perhaps seen as too close to asking for a recommendation. The question wasn't closed down, but it didn't get anywhere beyond that, either.

I'd like to reask and narrow it down, probably on SW recs, but I'm concerned that it might be deemed unsuitable whichever of SW or HW as it implicitly needs a combination of both. Hence checking first.

I'm leaning towards SW recs because the hypervisor is at the centre, and the question of compatible HW can be seen as a question about the hypervisor as well.

Advice appreciated on this question before reposting on sw recs, if I should?

Comment: Reading the linked question it seems it's completely unfit for this site here. We are recommending software meeting specific requirements – but to narrow it down, you rather want to know how hypervisors work. That's outsite the [tag:scope] of this site.